# Can you pass json into Dictionary<string, class> through a Url?

Tags: c#, json, url, dictionary

I am trying to pass a json parameter in a url into a dictionary. I have confirmed my json is valid on http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html . This my json object:

```
{
    "TagName": "property_details_address_address1",
    "ValuationDetails": {
        "TagValue": "Test",
        "ImageBase64": ""
    }
}
```

The Class:

```
public class ValuationDetails
{
  public string TagValue { get; set; }
  public string ImageBase64 { get; set; }
}
```

The method its passed to:

```
public void UploadValuationDetails(Dictionary<string, ValuationDetails> JsonResult, int Id)
{
   DatabaseHelper DBH = new DatabaseHelper();

   foreach (var item in JsonResult)
   {                 //(ValuationId ,TagName , TagValue           , ImageBase64)
     DBH.WSValuationDetailUpdate(Id, item.Key, item.Value.TagValue, item.Value.ImageBase64);
   }         
}
```

So my Url reads:

```
http://localhost:0000/APIService/UploadValuationDetails?JsonResult={TagName:"property_details_address_address1",ValuationDetails:{TagValue:"Test","ImageBase64":""}}&Id=4785
```

At the moment my JSON result shows a count of 0 but there should be an one object dictinary with the key of Tagname and a value where tagValue = test and ImageBase64 = ""

Comment: You should use `POST` for passing a block of JSON like this and not `GET` (and so not as parameters of the URL but as the request body instead).

Comment: @Lloyd This method will be call remotely like it was a webservice method. I am just trying to run some tests by physical entering the Url in my browser while running local host.

Comment: @Pomster: Have you tried url-encoding your parameter value?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your JSON sample, what I understand is you are trying to interpret it in a `Dictionary<string, ValuationDetails>`, but this can't be done as the value of `TagName` is not `ValuationDetails` in the `Dictionary` argument. So, you can classify it like below and give it another try:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public ValuationDetails ValuationDetails { get; set; }
}
```

And if you want that,

> there should be an one object dictinary with the key of Tagname and a value where tagValue = test and ImageBase64 = ""

then your JSON string should look something like:

```
{
    "TagName1": {
        "TagValue": "Test1",
        "ImageBase64": ""
    },
    "TagName2": {
        "TagValue": "Test2",
        "ImageBase64": ""
    }
}
```

and if this is the case, then your code you have provided with the loop should work fine enough.